# Start async task without waiting for it to finish, but check for completion

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been searching for a correct answer very hard, and all I find is either too complicated or not doing what i'm looking for.
The case is simple:

1. I want to start a task asynchronously every now and then. The same task always. There's no defined interval of time to start it (suppose it's random).
2. The task takes no arguments and doesn't return anything.
3. I don't want to wait for it to finish. It can't interfere with the rest of the program.
4. I want to check if it finished before firing it again. Don't want the same task running many times simultaneously. Just one each time.
5. I don't want to use timers or global variables like semaphors or something. Just a plain and clean solution for a very simple problem.

I've tried background workers, but the tasks overlap as I can't find a reliable way to check for completion. I've tried running tasks but they can't be restarted. I've tried with async/await but I don't want to wait for completion.

**EDIT:**
I'll provide more information. This application is for a facial recognition SW. I have to handle 3 cameras and I'm using EmguCV. Each camera suscribes to an ImageGrabbed Event called "ProcessFrame", so I have ProcessFrame1, ProcessFrame2 and ProcessFrame3. The Events are fired up at nearly the fps of each camera, given so, the frequency is very high. In each Event I take a capture and show it up in an ImageBox (Emgu's pictureBox). Every 5 captures I check if I have at least one capture of each camera, in which case, instead of showing it in the imagebox I perform a facial recognition on each image. This is the task I want to perform in a separate task, to avoid stopping the live video for each camera.

Right now I'm trying with a semaphore, as suggested by some of you, although I had some trouble on setting the chance to perform a DetectFace() in the three Events, so i just left one up.
Here is a snippet:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Instantiate each camera
    //Subscribe to ProcessFrame1, ProcessFrame2 and ProcessFrame3
}

private void ProcessFrame1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (captures[0] != null)  //captures[0] is the handle for the camera 1
    {
        Mat snapshot = new Mat();
        captures[0].Retrieve(snapshot);

        if (snapshot != null)
        {
            frameCounter1++;
            if (frameCounter1 > 5 && taskCompleted)
            {
                frameCounter1 = 0;

                if (images[0] == null)
                {
                    Image<Bgr, Byte> img = snapshot.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
                    images[0] = img.ToBitmap();
                }

                if (images[0] != null && images[1] != null && images[2] != null)
                {
                    Thread hilo = new Thread(() => DetectFace());
                    hilo.IsBackground = true;
                    hilo.Start();
                }

                return;
            }
            else
                imageBox1.Image = snapshot;
        }
    }
}

private void ProcessFrame2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (captures[1] != null)  //captures[1] is the handle for the camera 2
    {
        Mat snapshot = new Mat();
        captures[1].Retrieve(snapshot);

        if (snapshot != null)
        {
            frameCounter2++;
            if (frameCounter2 > 5 && taskCompleted)
            {
                frameCounter2 = 0;

                if (images[1] == null)
                {
                    Image<Bgr, Byte> img = snapshot.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
                    images[1] = img.ToBitmap();
                }

                //I used to have the checking to fire up another DetectFace here

                return;
            }
            else
                imageBox2.Image = snapshot;
        }
    }
}

private void ProcessFrame3(object sender, EventArgs e) //Same as ProcessFrame2

private void DetectFace()
{
    taskCompleted = false;

    //Processing of Images
    //Clear array of images

    taskCompleted = true;
}
```

Comment: You need to keep *some* state which says whether a Task is currently running. That could be a `SemaphoreSlim` (which is a very sensible suggestion), or it could be a `Task` that you check `IsCompleted` on, etc.

Comment: `bool isTaskRunning;` (along with suitable synchronization) is a pretty simple way of checking this...? there are of course *lots* of alternative ways of tracking this... I tend to favor a CEX in most cases where it is zero or one

Comment: It's hard to find the right answer without a look into your code and you don't specify whether you have to use System.Threading.Tasks.Task or not. Looking at the requirements seems like using a System.Threading.Thread with a loop and a System.Threading.ManualResetEvent should suffice.

Comment: As far as I know background worker class in c# support this isworkerbusy property that tells you is process is busy or not, so if overlapping is the only problem this should do it

Comment: @mjwills sorry, I meant "compare exchange" - i.e. `if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isRunning, 1, 0) == 0) { /* start new task */ } else { /* already running */ }`, obviously with a matching `Interlocked.Exchange(ref isRunning, 0);` in the `finally` of whatever the task is

Comment: What's the nature of the work this task is doing? As in, does it pick up some form of "queued" work to be processed?, with the queued work being provided by other parts of the program. If so, I'd suggest looking at a different approach such as producer/consumer (maybe with a `BlockingCollection` sitting in there). Otherwise, it's very difficult to avoid races (Task thinks its run out of work to do but hasn't "shut down enough" that something that's *just* queued a new item will know to restart the task)

Comment: @Joster: This is less "simple" than it first appears. There are two main problems: what does "finished" mean (there's always a race condition between the end of your code and the changing of the "is it finished?" state); and there's also the issue of detecting and responding to errors in the background tasks. The decisions around these issues will have major impacts on the design of the resulting solution.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever As you can see in my latest edit, I do use a shared resource like the images array (populated in the Events and used in the task). That's the most complicated part why I'm trying very hard to avoid races. Could you elaborate a little more on the BlockingCollection and producer/consumer approach? or point to some documentation to read? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieved the threadsafe solution using BlockingCollection. Thanks to @Damien_The_Unbeliever for pointing out to the right direction.

I think it's been an important lesson when working with images in a multithreading environment. I've learned that images are very vulnerable when sharing them in different threads.

As I posted in the question, here I have to take snapshots from X different webcams, show them in X different imageBoxes and, as fast as I can (without interrupting the fps of the shown video too much), perform an image processing instead of showing the frame in the imageBox. Using a BlockingCollection I don't need to stablish a frequency for processing the frames as I did before (every 5 frames). Now I can show the frame of each camera as long as I already have a frame from that camera added to the BlockingCollection.

Another important detail to note is, in the .NET documentation for BlockingCollection it says that by default it implements a FIFO as it's a ConcurrentQueue in the lower layer, but I think this isn't true, as I have had to define it myself when instantiating:

```
BlockingCollection<Tuple<int, Image>> tupleCollection = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<int, Image>>(new ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<int, Image>>(), X);
```

As the Take() method can't target the desired element in the collection, I had to use a tuple to know to which camera the frame belonged, and to take the frames in order I had to define the ConcurrentQueue.

So basically the pseudocode is this:

```
void Main()
{
   //Instantiate cameras
   //Subscribe to the ImageGrabbed events of each (producers)

   // A simple blocking consumer with no cancellation.
   Task.Run(() => DetectFace());
}

producer1(sender, e)
{
   //Get snapshot
...
   if (!tupleCollection.Any(x => x.Item1 == 1))
   {
      tupleCollection.Add(new Tuple<int, Image>(1, snapshot));
   }
   else
      imageBox1.Image = snapshot;
}

producer2(sender, e)
{
   //Get snapshot
...
   if (!tupleCollection.Any(x => x.Item1 == 2))
   {
      tupleCollection.Add(new Tuple<int, Image>(2, snapshot));
   }
   else
      imageBox2.Image = snapshot;
}
...
producerX(sender, e)
{
   //Get snapshot
...
   if (!tupleCollection.Any(x => x.Item1 == X))
   {
      tupleCollection.Add(new Tuple<int, Image>(X, snapshot));
   }
   else
      imageBoxX.Image = snapshot;
}

private void DetectFace()
{
   while (true)
   {
      Tuple<int, Image> data = null;
      try
      {
          data = tupleCollection.Take();
      }
      catch (InvalidOperationException) { }

      if (data != null)
      {
         //image processing
      }
   }
}
```

Most examples I have found use the condition IsCompletedAdded and IsCompleted to stop adding and consuming, but I needed it to be running forever, so the while(true) statement.

I have been running this code 24/7 within the last week, no racing faults by now, and the CPU processor is very limited, so I'm very satisfied with this solution and I think it's the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Tasks work with states so you can start your task, save a reference in a variable and check the current status of your task whenever you want.

Here is the .NET documentation to read up on the different states of a task:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.status?view=netframework-4.7.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus?view=netframework-4.7.2

sadly I'm not able to give you a code example at the moment but I hope the idea helps.